# How to use routerLink with innerHTML

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using Angular 6. I just want to create a dynamic route by using the `innerHTML`. I tried the following code but it is not working.
In the component file, I wrote the following code inside the constructor:

```js
this.anchor = "<a routerLink='login'>Dynamic Login</a>"
```

In the template file, I wrote the following code:

```html
<div [innerHtml]="anchor"></div>
```

Answer (score 16):

There is one hacky solution that I used when encountered same problem as you did since I didn't find anything better. In template I had `span` where I was setting `innerHtml` that html was coming from server and it could have `a` tag as well as any other formatting html tags. So the solution is to add click event:

```html
<span [innerHtml]="customHtml" (click)="processLinks($event)"></span>
```

And in our ts file process them:

```js
customHtml: string = 'Hey <a href="/help/">this is</a> a link';

// Don't forget to import and inject the router
constructor(private router: Router) {}

// ...

processLinks(e) {
  const element: HTMLElement = e.target;
  if (element.nodeName === 'A') {
    e.preventDefault();
    const link = element.getAttribute('href');
    this.router.navigate([link]);
  }
}
```

Notice that you can do anything with the link here, if you need you can add some conditions or transform links before navigating to them.

Hope it helps. I know it's not the best solution, there must be something better. But that's what I came up with in a rush.

Comment: This concept also worked for me in ReactJS.

Answer (score 2):

```js
this.anchor = "<a routerLink='login'>Dynamic Login</a>"
```

```html
<div [innerHtml]="anchor"></div>
```

Above codes won't cause Angular to process anything Angular-specific in `anchor`.

Angular replaces Angular specific markup at build time with generated code. Markup added at runtime won't be processed by Angular.

To add HTML that contains Angular-specific markup (property or value binding, components, directives, pipes, ...) it is required to add the dynamic module and compile components at runtime. This answer provides more details [How can I use/create a dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/3339907)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. I created a custom directive. It scans dom tree in innerHTML then make decision

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appDynamicRouterLink]'
})

/**
 * This directive is used to dynamically add routerLink to a tag.
 * @author Hakkı Konu
 */
export class DynamicRouterLinkDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private router: Router) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const links = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
        console.log('links', links);
        links.forEach(link => {
            const routerLink = link.getAttribute('routerLink');
            if (routerLink) {
                const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([routerLink]);
                link.setAttribute('href', urlTree.toString());
                link.addEventListener('click', event => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
                });
            } else {
                const href = link.getAttribute('href');
                if (href && href.startsWith('/')) {
                    const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([href]);
                    link.setAttribute('href', urlTree.toString());
                    link.addEventListener('click', event => {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

--

usage:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content" appDynamicRouterLink></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Chebotarsky solution is good and prooves the concept.

I can show you how I've used it as a pipe for long description where you encounter more links.

1. I've created a pipe to replace some words with <a [routerLink]="build/your/${url},{$here}">{initialWord}

**docs.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'docs' })
export class DocsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: string, item: IStack): SafeHtml {
    value = value.replace(DocsKeywords.language, `<a class="doc-type" [routerLink]="/tabs/search,${item.area[0]},${item.id}">${DocsKeywords.language}</a>`);
    value = value.replace(DocsKeywords.frontend, `<a class="doc-type" [routerLink]="/tabs/search,${item.area[0]},${item.id}">${DocsKeywords.frontend}</a>`);
    value = value.replace(DocsKeywords.framework, `<a class="doc-type" [routerLink]="/tabs/search,${item.area[0]},${item.id}">${DocsKeywords.framework}</a>`);

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Afterwards my rendered HTML & DOM looks like this:
[image]
[image]

2. Then in your component where you use it

**some-component.html**

```
<p class="description" [innerHtml]="item.longDescription | docs: item">
```

**some-component.ts**

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("doc-type")) {
      const urlSegments = e.target.getAttribute('[routerlink]').split(',');
      this.router.navigate(urlSegments);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I solved it.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[linkify]",
})

// * Apply Angular Routing behavior, PreventDefault behavior
export class CustomLinkDirective {
  @Input()
  appStyle: boolean = true;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private ref: ElementRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {}

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    href && this.router.navigate([href]);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.ref.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((a: HTMLElement) => {
        const href = a.getAttribute("href");
        href &&
          this.appStyle &&
          a.classList.add("text-indigo-600", "hover:text-indigo-500");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

use it

```
 <p linkify
    class="mt-3 text-lg text-gray-500 include-link"
    [innerHtml]="apiSectionText"
  ></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

My decision for subj with innerHtml, i18n translate and routerLink below:
component html:

```
<p 
     (click)="routerlinkClicked($event)" 
     [innerHTML]="signupSuccessText"
></p>
```

component.ts:

```
public signupSuccessText: SafeHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.translate.instant('signup.successReport.body.text'))

constructor(
    private sanitizer:                  DomSanitizer,
    private router:                     Router,
    public  translate:                  TranslateService
) { }

public routerlinkClicked(event: Event): void {
    const target: HTMLElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const attributes: NamedNodeMap = target.attributes;
    const redirectUrl: string = attributes && attributes['routerlink'] ? attributes['routerlink'].value : '';
    if (redirectUrl) {
        this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
    }
}
```

finally translate i18n en.json:

```
"signup.successReport.body.text": "You have almost finished. <br /> Please, check your email and follow <br /> the verification link to complete you registration.<br /><br /> After you finish, come back and <a routerLink='/login' class='reset__link' data-test-id='loginLink'>log in</a>.",
```

cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. I just replaced the `<a routerLink="/something">Something</a>`

to

```
<a href="#/something">Something</a>
```

And it works just fine

Comment: this reloads the page.