# Enable routerLink in anchor tags in Angular InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, anchor, innerhtml

I have an XML database and an XSLT document to transform this XML into HTML before passing to the server and an Angular client. I am then displaying this HTML using `[innerHTML]`. I would like to be able to use anchor tags to navigate within the page (e.g. footnotes) and eventually to different components. I have included example code for the footnotes. Given that Angular removes routerLink attributes when using innerHTML I am working on a solution editing DOM elements and manually adding attributes and on-click behavior. However, this doesn't seem very Angular-y so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
document = '<a routerLink="." fragment="45"><sup>45</sup></a><p>Other text</p><div id="45>Footnote text</div>'


<div id="view-panel" [innerHTML]="document | safe: 'html'">
```

Comment: What about this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350647/how-to-use-routerlink-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

I've created a package: [ngx-event-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-event-handler) that allows you to do things you shouldn't do but sometimes have to. Like listen to document event to detect a outside-element-click or in your case handle anchor clicks from innerHTML.

Here the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routerlink-innerhtml):

```
<div (handleEvent)="routerlinkClicked($event)" 
     [inclusion]="['a']" 
      id="view-panel"
      [innerHTML]="document">
</div>

routerlinkClicked(element : HTMLElement) {
   this.router.navigate([element.getAttribute('routerlink')]);
}
```

In the last example of this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-event-handler) I handle href's